# Changing classic code to functional

Tags: java, functional-programming, chess

I have the following portion of **ugly** (but working) code for checking if fields on a chessboard are vacant:

```
if (abs(xDst - xSrc) == abs(yDst - ySrc)) {
            boolean backslashMove = xSrc < xDst && ySrc > yDst || xSrc > xDst && ySrc < yDst;
            if (backslashMove) {
                int y = max(ySrc, yDst) - 1;
                for (int x = min(xSrc, xDst) + 1; x < max(xSrc, xDst); x++) {

                    if (board.getActiveChessmanAt(x, y).isAlive()) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    y--;
                }
            } else { //slash move
```

Obviously, it examines fields between coordinates (xScr, ySrc) and (xDst, yDst) in Bishop-like line of move.

I'm trying to transform this with using IntStream:

```
if (backslashMove) {
                final int y = max(ySrc, yDst) - 1;

                if (IntStream.range(min(xSrc, xDst) + 1, max(xSrc, xDst))
                        .anyMatch(x -> board.getActiveChessmanAt(x, y).isAlive()))
                return false;
```

How can I perform y-- in this case? It has to be final if it's about to be used within 'anyMatch' command

Comment: I’m sure this comment will get ignored but there really is absolutely no point trying to write this using streams. I’m not convinced replacing a for loop by IntStream.range() constitutes functional programming anyway.

Comment: Hmmm... This code is just ugly and too much nested. Any idea how to polish it, not necessarly wint IntStream?

See? Your comment wasn't ingored :)

Comment: I agree with that, but I’d try breaking it up into smaller methods.

Comment: That was my first idea, but the whole method is like that:
 'boolean noObstacles(BoardField src, BoardField dest) {'
'if ( the line from src to dest is HORIZONTAL)'

{ if (any chessman along the way)
  return false;
}

if ( the line from src to dest is VERTICAL)

{ if (any chessman along the way)
  return false;
}

if ( the line from src to dest is LEAN)

{ if (any chessman along the way)
  return false;
}

return true;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you *really* need to rewrite it using streams, then you can use the fact that both `x` and `y` are incremented simultaneously. So you can build a range of *increments* instead of the range of x-values:

```
final int xSrc = min(xSrc, xDst) + 1;
final int xDst = max(xSrc, xDst);
final int ySrc = max(ySrc, yDst) - 1;

if (IntStream.range(0, xDst - xSrc)
    .anyMatch(distance -> board.getActiveChessmanAt(xSrc + distance, ySrc + distance).isAlive())) {
    return false;
}
```

---

**In general,** it's not possible to use a non-final local variable from the "parent" method directly. Java doesn't support *real closures*. You would need a wrapper object for this (`AtomicInteger` is an often suggested candidate), or you could make the non-final variable a class field (note the potential thread safety problems). To me personally, these both "tricks" are bad.

Comment: It's an ad-hoc code rewriting for this very case and can't seen as a general-purpose solution in the sense of using non-final local variables from lambdas. The proposed solutions avoids using non-final variables. Please let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: It seems it works, at least for "bakslash" moves. I'm trying to figure out how to deal with "slash" moves.

I don't exactly get how distance -> board.getActiveChessmanAt(minX + distance, maxY + distance) works

Answer (score 1):

What you need is not functional programming in terms of streams/folds.
Instead of, you should refactor your actual code to make it clearer/shorter/better.

You could for example :

- extract the parts of logic scattered in the actual method in specific methods with meaningful names
- use structured objects rather than too fine unitary variable
- remove undesirable nesting :  use early exit and not required conditional statements may help

It could give :

```
// -> extract method + structured objects
if (!isPointsMatch(pointSrc, pointDst)) {
    return false; // -> early exit
}

// -> extract method + structured objects
if (isBackslashMove(pointSrc, pointDst)) {
     if (board.hasAnyActiveChessmanAlive(pointSrc, pointDst)) {
          return false;  
      }
}
// else slash move -> The else is useless
// ...
```

Comment: Your answer looks interesting, but I don't actually know how to apply it :(

Answer (score 0):

Your original code snipped is *procedural*. Your functional approach does not work well. So how about an *object oriented* approach?

```
class Position{
  private final int x, y;
  public Position(int x, int y){
     this.x=x;
     this.y=y;
  }
  public getX(){
    return x;
  }
  public getY(){
    return y;
  }
}
```

---

```
interface Move {
  Position moveFrom(Position start);
}

interface Figure {
  Collection<Move> getPossibleMoves(Position start, Board board);
}
```

---

```
class Bishop implements Figure {
  private final Collection<Move> moves = new HashSet<>();
  public Bishop(){
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()-2,start.getY()-1));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()-2,start.getY()+1));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()+2,start.getY()-1));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()+2,start.getY()+1));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()-1,start.getY()-2));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()-1,start.getY()+2));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()+1,start.getY()-2));
      moves.add(start->new Position(start.getX()+1,start.getY()+2));
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<Move> getPossibleMoves(Position start, Board board){
    return moves.stream()
                .filter({ Position end = m.moveFrom(start);
                          return board.isOnBorad(end.getX(),end.getY())
                               && board.getActiveChessmanAt(end.getX(), end.getY()).isAlive()})
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  }
}
```

---

Another implementation of `Figure` might return a separate `Move` instance for each step until it reaches a limit:

```
class Tower implements Figure {
   enum Direction {
      NORTH(1,0),EAST(0,1),SOUTH(-1,0),WEST(0,-1);
      private final Position change;
      private Direction(int x, int y){
         change = new Position(x, y);
      }
      public Position getNextFrom(Position start){
          return new Position(start.getX()+change.getX(),start.getX()+change.getY());
      }

      @Override
      public Collection<Move> getPossibleMoves(Position start, Board board){
         Collection<Move> moves = new HashSet<>();
         for(Direction direction : Direction.values()){
           Position current = direction.getNextFrom(start);
           while( board.isOnBorad(current.getX(),current.getY())
               && board.getActiveChessmanAt(current.getX(), current.getY()).isAlive()){
             moves.add(p-> new Position(current.getX(),current.getY());
           }
        }
        return moves;
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tim. In your code for **Bishop** you actually implemented move possibilities for **Knight**

Comment: public boolean moveCompliesWithRules(BoardField destField) {

        int deltaX = abs(destField.getTableXCoord() - field.getTableXCoord());
        int deltaY = abs(destField.getTableYCoord() - field.getTableYCoord());

       return (deltaX == 2 && deltaY == 1)
                || (deltaX == 1 && deltaY == 2); 
    }  is actually better implementation for a Knight